# Should my seq2seq RNN idea work?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I want to predict stock price.

Normally, people would feed the input as a sequence of stock prices.
Then they would feed the output as the same sequence but shifted to the left.

When testing, they would feed the output of the prediction into the next input timestep like this:[image]

I have another idea, which is to fix the sequence length, for example 50 timesteps.
The input and output are exactly the same sequence.

When training, I replace last 3 elements of the input by zero to let the model know that I have no input for those timesteps.

When testing, I would feed the model a sequence of 50 elements. The last 3 are zeros. The predictions I care are the last 3 elements of the output.

Would this work or is there a flaw in this idea?

Comment: Please visit https://datascience.stackexchange.com for that question instead. Even so, I would advise you to try what you have just proposed and see the results for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main flaw of this idea is that it does not add anything to the model's learning, and it reduces its capacity, as you force your model to learn identity mapping for first 47 steps (50-3). Note, that providing 0 as inputs is equivalent of not providing input for an RNN, as zero input, after multiplying by a weight matrix is still zero, so the only source of information is bias and output from previous timestep - both are already there in the original formulation. Now second addon, where we have output for first 47 steps - there is nothing to be gained by learning the identity mapping, yet network will have to "pay the price" for it - it will need to use weights to encode this mapping in order not to be penalised.

So in short - yes, your idea will work, but it is nearly impossible to get better results this way as compared to the original approach (as you do not provide any new information, do not really modify learning dynamics, yet you limit capacity by requesting identity mapping to be learned per-step; especially that it is an extremely easy thing to learn, so gradient descent will discover this relation first, before even trying to "model the future").